# group by multiple times into object using typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have some difficulties to find out how can i group by multiple data inside array of objects. my first code show how i did to group by my first data which is formuleWazari. i want after this group by do another one.

my code :

```
const groupBy = (array, key) => {
  // Return the end result
  return array.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
    // If an array already present for key, push it to the array. Else create an array and push the object
    (result[formuleWazari(currentValue[key])] = result[formuleWazari(currentValue[key])]  || []).push(
      new wazari(currentValue['product'], currentValue['warranty'])
     // new wazariFinal(currentValue['warranty'])
    );

    // Return the current iteration `result` value, this will be taken as next iteration `result` value and accumulate
    return result;
  }, {}); // empty object is the initial value for result object

};


var  personGroupedByColor = groupBy(obj.warrantySettings, 'formula');
```

this code give me this result:

```
{
  "Basic": [
    {
      "product": 3,
      "warranty": 1
    },
    {
      "product": 3,
      "warranty": 8
    },
    {
      "product": 3,
      "warranty": 6
    },
    {
      "product": 4,
      "warranty": 7
    },
    {
      "product": 4,
      "warranty": 14
    }
  ],
  "Confort": [
    {
      "product": 3,
      "warranty": 1
    },
    {
      "product": 3,
      "warranty": 8
    },
    {
      "product": 3,
      "warranty": 2
    },
    {
      "product": 3,
      "warranty": 3
    },
    {
      "product": 3,
      "warranty": 10
    },
    {
      "product": 3,
      "warranty": 11
    },
    {
      "product": 3,
      "warranty": 6
    },
    {
      "product": 4,
      "warranty": 7
    },
    {
      "product": 4,
      "warranty": 14
    }
  ],

}
```

i want to group again by the product. how can i do this so i can have the json look like this (thank's in advance for the help guys) :

```
{
  "Basic": [

    { "product":[
                3 :{
                  "warranty": 1,
                  "warranty": 8
                },
                 4 :{
                  "warranty": 10,
                  "warranty": 12
                },

]
]}}
```

Comment: Will you please add more clarity to the question? what you are trying to do in group by function and please add the inputs like warranty settings and also the desired output clearly.

Answer (score 0):

i found out the solution :

```
const groupBy = (array, key) => {
      // Return the end result
      return array.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
        // If an array already present for key, push it to the array. Else create an array and push the object
        (result[formuleWazari(currentValue[key])]  = result[formuleWazari(currentValue[key])]  || []).push(
      );
        (result[formuleWazari(currentValue[key])] [productWazari(currentValue['product'])]  = result[formuleWazari(currentValue[key])] [productWazari(currentValue['product'])]  || []).push(

          garantieWazari(currentValue['warranty'])
        );
        // Return the current iteration `result` value, this will be taken as next iteration `result` value and accumulate
        return result;
      }, {}); // empty object is the initial value for result object
    };
```